# \bibliography{} doesn't show all citations!

Tags: bibliographies

**reference.tex:**

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref}
```

**ref.bib:**

```
@article{patel2011performance,
title={Performance analysis of content management systems-joomla, drupal and wordpress},
author={Patel, Savan K and Rathod, VR and Prajapati, Jigna B},
journal={International Journal of Computer Applications},
volume={21},
number={4},
pages={39--43},
year={2011},
publisher={Citeseer}
}

@inproceedings{patel2011joomla,
title={Joomla, Drupal and WordPress-a statistical comparison of open source CMS},
author={Patel, Savan K and Rathod, V R and Parikh, Satyen},
booktitle={Trendz in Information Sciences and Computing (TISC), 2011 3rd International Conference on},
pages={182--187},
year={2011},
organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{mirdha2014comparative,
title={Comparative analysis of open source content management systems},
author={Mirdha, Aakanksha and Jain, Apurva and Shah, Kunal},
booktitle={Computational Intelligence and Computing Research (ICCIC), 2014 IEEE International Conference on},
pages={1--4},
year={2014},
organization={IEEE}
}

@misc{shreves2011open,
title={Open source cms market share. White paper, Water \& Stone},
author={Shreves, Ric},
year={2011}
}
```

[image: the unexpected output]

I was able to get all my references sorted out in the beginning, but later i was not able to get the same.
(I did search the same question but didn't get an exact answer!)

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) on this site we prefer to get fully compilable minimal examples that we can copy and test without having to add anything. (3) Bibtex only adds stuff to the bibliography that are actually **cited**, the code you present does not show any citations, so that might very vell be why you do not get any result. Just to test your bib file, you can add `\nocite{*}` to your doc, then run latex, bibtex, latex, latex in order to show everything from your bib file.

Comment: Instead of adding "Solved" to your question title, you should ask user @daleif to answeryour question. Then you can upvote (with a little more rep) and accept his answer to say "Thank you" to him ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thing the confuses a lot of new bibtex users is that bibtex will only include things that are actually cited. If you want more than that you need to tell it.

I this case my guess was that no data was cited and thus bibtex produces an empty bibliography.

A common thing to do is to add `\nocite{*}` to tell bibtex to include **everything** from the given bib file(s). Then you'll see how bibtex handles the data you have prepared.

With bibtex and similar, remember you will often need several compilations before everything it up to date. If `\nocite{*}` is **not** used, then every time you cite something new, you'll need

```
latex, bibtex, latex, latex
```